# C#: Count a dictionary Key (word) occurrence in a String (text) present in a list

Tags: c#, string, algorithm, list, dictionary

I already have a dictionary that contains WORDS with their COUNT (high occurrence) taken from whole text (file).

Next step is to check each WORD occurrence in each sentence of Text.

Saving that sentence that has high occurrence of a word.

For example:

```
List<string> list = new List<string>();
list.Add("This this is a string.");
        list.Add("String words accurences needs to be checked.");
        list.Add("how many times do this string text conatin words?");
        list.Add("how how how word words words");
        list.Add("This this This this");

        Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>(StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
        dict.Add("this", 7);
        dict.Add("how", 4);
        dict.Add("string", 2);
        dict.Add("words", 2);
        dict.Add("occurences", 1);
        dict.Add("checked", 1);
```

Code that checks "HOW,4" comes in 2nd and 3rd string of list and 3rd string has high occurrence of it.
It should output 3rd "sentence" string with high occurrence 3 int of word HOW.
and so on.. check for other words in dictionary.

Dictionary be like:
{sentence, word, occurrence}
Occurrence should be high or same count.

Next task is to count word length of each sentence.

How can I get sentences that have highest number of occurrences of words present in dictionary? Deleting word from Dictionary after checking. Saving sentence with count in dictionary.

Comment: ...And the question is?

Comment: And the Question is, how can I get sentences that have highest number of occurrences of words present in dictionary.
Deleting word from Dictionary after checking.
Saving sentence with count in dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added code, having more time complexity, but you can retrieve sentence having maximum occurrences of a word.
Your task is to make it compatible with your problem and try to solve your problem by your own.

```
 //Function to print maximum occurances of word from dictionary with sentence
    public static void FindSentenceWithMaxOcc(List<string> list, Dictionary<string, int>dict){

        int maxSentenceIndex = 0, index = 0;
        int maxCount = int.MinValue;
        string word = "";

        //Iterate through dictionary containing words with total occurances
        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> kv in dict){

            //Iterating through sentences present in list
            foreach(string element in list){
                //Split all words using space
                string[] words = element.Split(' ');
                //Count all occurrances of dictionary key in sentence
                int temp = Array.FindAll(words, s => s.Equals(kv.Key.Trim())).Length;

                //Get max occurrances 
                if(temp > maxCount){
                    maxCount = temp;
                    maxSentenceIndex = index;
                    word = kv.Key;
                }
                index++;
            }
            index = 0;
        }

        //Print result
        Console.WriteLine("Maximum count: " +maxSentenceIndex);
        Console.WriteLine("Word: " +word);
        Console.WriteLine("Sentence" +list[maxSentenceIndex]);
    }
```

Time complexity: O(n^2)

Implementation : [DotNet Fiddler](https://dotnetfiddle.net/OMtPJ3)

Can we reduce its time complexity or can we make it more efficient?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158968/discussion-on-answer-by-prasad-telkikar-c-count-a-dictionary-key-word-occurr).

Answer (score 0):

What I was trying to do,

```
void count(List<string> l, Dictionary<string, int> d)
{
    var text = l;
    var wp = new Regex(@"\w+");

    foreach (Match m in wp.Matches(text[0])) //using text[0] for 1st string
    {
        if (!d.ContainsKey(m.Value))
        { d.Add(m.Value, 1); }
        else
            d[m.Value]++;
    }
}

//for Printing
foreach(var pair in dict) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0 },{1}", pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

Comment: here you are increasing occurrence of that word in dictionary. because of that you are getting 4-how.

Comment: No, I am actually getting the same dictionary that I initialized, but with the addition of 2 more entries.